# How can my buton just be pressed once every a determined time?

Tags: html, jquery, button, onclick, intervals

I am using this function so the button only enables when the form is valid

```
 const re = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
$(function() {
  $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
  $('#textarea, #email, #name').change(function() {
    if ($('#name').val() != '' && re.test($('#email').val()) != '' && $('#textarea').val() != '') {
      $('#button').attr('disabled', false);
    } else {
      $('#button').attr('disabled', true);
    }
  });
});
```

but I also want to have like an interval of time, since when the form is valid, the button can be pressed several times in a row and too many emails are sent until the php-form-handler redirects me to the index.

```
<div id="button-container">
                    <button type="submit" id="button" disabled></button>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Please clarify:  you don't want the button enabled immediately but "also have an interval" (so form validates, but wait, then enable)?   You want the button for only a single click, then disabled again (until?)?  You want to click the button, then disable it for an interval, then re-enable it?  You want it so if they click if 100 times really quickly it only works once (better to disable it after click than this though)?  Some other meaning *"also want to have an interval"*

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Timeouts_and_intervals

Comment: It is a bit complicated to explain as I don't speak english so well but, the scene is the following: in my form, when you fill the 3 inputs, button enables so it can be submitted. There are like 3 o 4 seconds between the moment when you submit the form and the page redirects you to the index (it was specified in php $headers location). In those 3 or 4 secs, the button is always enabled, so people can submit the form a lot of times until they are redirected to the index. What I want is to disable the button again after it was pressed once.

Comment: Looks like the key is that the "page redirects" when the server has completed.  So you only need the button to be clickable *once* (then the redirect will either give a different page or a blank form).  In which case you can just disable the submit button when your form submits:  `$("form").on("submit", function() { $('#button').attr('disabled', true); });`